# Clang++ /usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: armelf_linux_eabi

Tags: android, linker, c++17, clang++

I am developing a cross platform `C++` project for Android with `armv7-a` architecture on Linux `64 bit` as host machine. I use `Android NDK r25c` and stopped to build the final executable file by this output from my makefile:

```
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Packet.cpp -o     ../bin/Packet.o     -std=c++17 
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o     ../bin/Client.o     -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o     ../bin/Server.o     -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Shell.cpp -o      ../bin/Shell.o      -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o ../bin/Filesystem.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Filesystem.o ../bin/Shell.o ../bin/Packet.o ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: armelf_linux_eabi
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu i386pep i386pe elf64bpf
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [makefile:39: android] Error 1
```

All `*.o` files have been constructed and running `file` command on them gives:

> ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

But the very last command to link all `*.o` files together and create the executable file fails.

Does anybody have any idea?

**This is after my own solution (in case anyone is interested):**

The installation of Android NDK was just downloading and extraction of the zip file. To set up the cross compiling toolchains, I would refer to the `Solution` that I made after a lot of `trial and error` because actually I could not find any assistance anywhere. The build environment was nothing but liunx terminal (no Android studio nor Gradle).

And this is my makefile:

```
export NDK_DIR     = /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export ANDROID_CXX = $(NDK_DIR)/bin/clang++
export TARGET      = --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi31 
export SYSROOT     = --sysroot=$(NDK_DIR)/sysroot
export CPP_VERSION = -std=c++17                          

android:
# compile single *.cpp files into separate *.o files
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c Packet.cpp -o     ../bin/Packet.o     $(CPP_VERSION)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o     ../bin/Client.o     $(CPP_VERSION)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o     ../bin/Server.o     $(CPP_VERSION)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c Shell.cpp -o      ../bin/Shell.o      $(CPP_VERSION)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o ../bin/Filesystem.o $(CPP_VERSION)

# compile two entry points for server and client and convert their *.cpp files into separate *.o files
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o $(CPP_VERSION)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o $(CPP_VERSION)

# compile and link all object files into two separate *.out files (one for client and one for server)
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Filesystem.o ../bin/Shell.o ../bin/Packet.o ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
    $(ANDROID_CXX) $(TARGET) $(SYSROOT) -o ../bin/server_executable.out ../bin/Filesystem.o ../bin/Shell.o ../bin/Packet.o ../bin/Server.o ../bin/server_main.o

# remove single *.o files
    rm -f ../bin/Android/Packet.o    
    rm -f ../bin/Android/Client.o    
    rm -f ../bin/Android/Server.o    
    rm -f ../bin/Android/Shell.o     
    rm -f ../bin/Android/Filesystem.o
    rm -f ../bin/Android/client_main.o
    rm -f ../bin/Android/server_main.o
```

Comment: The system linker usually is not set up for cross-platform linking. Doesn't the installation of the Android development kit include a proper cross-platform build system, including its own linker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

The whole pain now is gone by simply making a ***`symbolic link`*** of `clang-14` inside `/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin` directory.

Perhaps, if in future, someone else will face the same problem as me, here is the solution:

1. go to your toolchain's binary directory (e.g. mine is `/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin`)
2. there should be a text file called `clang++`. it is just a wrapper file pointing to `clang-14` compiler binary fie which resides in the same path, if you look for it.
3. rename this text file to something else just for not losing it later (I did `mv ./clang++ ./clang++1`)
4. Now make a symbolic link for your compiler by  `ln -s ./clang-14 ./clang++`.
5. now you can call this symbolic link from your makefile and this is the output:

   ```
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Packet.cpp -o     ../bin/Packet.o     -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o     ../bin/Client.o     -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o     ../bin/Server.o     -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Shell.cpp -o      ../bin/Shell.o      -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o ../bin/Filesystem.o -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o -std=c++17
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Filesystem.o ../bin/Shell.o ../bin/Packet.o ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
   /usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33  --sysroot=/usr/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -o ../bin/server_executable.out ../bin/Filesystem.o ../bin/Shell.o ../bin/Packet.o ../bin/Server.o ../bin/server_main.o
   ```